# telepat Java Eclipse IDE plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, telepat

I am building an application prototype for my client. I am excited about using telepat api. Problem is, I am a newbie developer. Is there a telepat api plugin available for Java Eclipse IDE? If so, it can help me speed up the prototyping process. Does anyone know of a telepat plugin for eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

@Rajeev. Unfortunately there's no Eclipse IDE at this time. However, the API requests are fully documented here: http://docs.telepat.io/api.html

It might not be trivial for a new developer, but you should be able to use big parts of the Android Telepat SDK (https://github.com/telepat-io/telepat-android-sdk) as a client for your Java application. Of course, the GCM transport is not going to work, and the project is configured for gradle rather than ANT, but a lot of the source code should be reusable.

(This is not related to this question specifically, but if you do decide to use the Android SDK, feel free to post any questions here and we're also ready to accept pull requests on this)